# laravel passport auth:api keeps returns Unauthenticated

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using laravel passport and trying to consume the api. After following the docs, everything is good but after a few days, the auth:api keeps returning 'message: "Unauthenticated."' I checked the docs multiple times and couldn't figure out what went wrong. I've also cleared all cache and configs but still the same result. The laravel_token is present in the request header.

[image: request header]

**Api.php**

```
Route::middleware(['auth:api'])->group(function () {
    Route::resource('comment', 'API\CommentController');
    Route::resource('notification', 'API\NotificationController');
});
```

**Auth.php**

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

**User.php**

```
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable,HasApiTokens;
}
```

**AuthServiceProvider**

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Passport::routes();
}
```

**Kernel.php**

```
'web' => [
    \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class, //last 
 ],
```

Comment: Change `Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function(Request $request)` instead of  `Route::middleware(['auth:api'])->group(function ()` in `Api.php`

Comment: tried it but it didnt work. I need the group function cause i got multiple route::resource @Sobir

Comment: if you are using cookies can u clear all cookies relevant to this page then check this out. if not how do you set token in header or cookie?

Comment: i alraedy tried clearing all the cookies and cache but still doenst work. The token is automatically set by default because im using the CreateFreshApiToken to consume own api as mentioned in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript @TEFO